# activar una funcion cuando una clase esta activa javascript

Tags: javascript

Hola estoy tratando de activar este codigo solo cuando una clase sidemenu_open del body esta desactivada

```
if (document.getElementsByClassName(".sidemenu_open")) {
console.log("la clase esta activa");


} else {
console.log("Se ejecuta si no la tiene");
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
// add padding top to show content behind navbar
navbar_height = document.querySelector('.navbar').offsetHeight;
document.body.style.paddingTop = navbar_height + 'px';
}); 
}
```

Comment: ¿Se puede activar y desactivar la clase dinámicamente, una vez ya cargado el body?

Comment: si, la clase sidemenu_open activa un sidebar que esta fuera del canvas y lo muestra, estonces quiero que cuando este activo no muestre ese codigo

Comment: ¿Cómo agregas esa clase?

Answer (score 1):

Más bien necesitas esto:

```js
$hay_sidebarmenu_open = document.getElementsByClassName("sidemenu_open");
if ($hay_sidebarmenu_open.length > 0) {
  console.log("la clase esta activa");
} else {
  console.log("Se ejecuta si no la tiene");
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    // add padding top to show content behind navbar
    navbar_height = document.querySelector('.navbar').offsetHeight;
    document.body.style.paddingTop = navbar_height + 'px';
    console.log(navbar_height)
  });
}
```

```html
<body class="no_hay_sidemenu_open" style="background-color:grey">
<nav class="navbar">Hola mundo!</nav>
</body>
```

Cambios:

1. Llamabas mal a la clase, pues le agregabas la notación del punto cuando no es necesario al usar **getElementsByClassName()** pues ya espera una clase.
2. Tu condicional siempre se cumplia pues **getElementsByClassName()** siempre se ejecutaba hubiera o no hubiera esa clase. He usado la propiedad **length** para saber con certeza si hay o no hay elementos que usen esa clase y así verificarlo de forma correcta.

Comment: si, gracias por lo del punto en la clase se me habia pasado, pero creo que tengo que ejecutar el codigo cuando la clase esta activa pero quitando el padding

Comment: Eso del padding ni idea, no forma parte de la pregunta ni hay código que revisar que involucre ese padding, lo siento.  En mi respuesta me he inventado el html porque tu no has puesto ninguno, pero seguramente el tuyo es distinto.

Comment: el HTML es la etiqueta body solamente

Comment: ¿y esto que es entonces? document.querySelector('.navbar')

Comment: es un navbar predeterminado de boostrap, pero la clase que quiero se activa en en el body

Comment: He modificado mi respuesta, supongo que ahora se parece algo más a lo que tu tienes, pero de todas formas eso de poner o no el padding es tu decisión, yo tan solo te indico como detectar si la clase está puesta o no, que es lo que en definitiva preguntabas.

Answer (score 0):

Igual lo que quieres es que si un elemento tiene determinada clase, ejecute el código

```
<div id="test">
    <nav class="nav"> Hola</nav>
</div>



const elem = document.getElementsById("test")
if (elem.classList.includes("sidemenu_open")) {
console.log("la clase esta activa");


} else {
    console.log("Se ejecuta si no la tiene");
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
        // add padding top to show content behind navbar
        navbar_height = document.querySelector('.navbar').offsetHeight;
        document.body.style.paddingTop = navbar_height + 'px';
    }); 
}
```